# doOnDispose does not get called when subscribing on a background scheduler

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

I am trying to bridge some existing rx code and api that uses futures. When I 
manually dispose an observable I would expect onDispose() to be always called. It usually does but when I specify a custom scheduler it sometimes does not get called. My example:

```
class Work {

private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

fun getFuture(): ListenableFuture<String> {

    val future = ResolvableFuture.create<String>()

    disposables.add(

            Observable.fromCallable {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000)
                } catch (ex: InterruptedException) {

                }
                "1"
            }.firstOrError()
                .onErrorReturn { "2" }
                .doOnDispose {
                    println("disposing 1 on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                    //sometimes this dispose does not get called
                    future.set("2")
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .doOnDispose {
                    println("disposing 2 on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                    //only this dispose gets called every time
                    //future.set("2")
                }
                .subscribe(Consumer {
                    future.set("2")
                })
    )

    return future
}

fun stop() {
    disposables.clear()
}

}

@Test
fun `doOnDispose does not get called`() {
    println("------------")

    for (i in 1..100) {

        val work = Work()

        val future = work.getFuture()

        println("Cancelling")

        work.stop()

        println("Getting ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        val result = future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

        assertEquals("2", result)

        println("------------")
    }
}
```

What happens is only the second onDispose gets called every time. The one before .subscribeOn() is sometimes not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing modes here. Don't do that. Either use RxJava or use Futures. You have created the start of a maintenance nightmare.

A thread is created on the `io()` scheduler, which immediately sleeps for 2 seconds. The observer chain is disposed ("disposing 2"), releasing resources, and the `dispose()` works its way back up the chain. However, `dispose()` won't do anything on the `io()` thread because it is blocked by `sleep()`. There is now a race condition whether the thread completes or the dispose operation works first.

I can't advise you how to fix the problem as I don't know what you are trying to do. I just know that what you have is unreliable.

Comment: Yes I definitely would not use futures but you somehow need to glue android workmanger with Rxjava otherwise you have to use toBlocking() which is bad  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes

Comment: Well, `get()` on `Future` is also blocking. I suspect that you may not be clear on the lifecycle of an observer chain: If you need to free up resources when the operation finishes or is no longer needed, it is probably better to create an observable that manages all of these steps.